# Optimizing graph analysis

Tags: c++, optimization, algorithm

I've implemented the Floyd Warshall algorithm in [this](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=762) problem.  However, as this is my first time in handling with adjacency list, I was not able to make it memory efficient.

I used a 1000*1000 and another list of 1000 size but I have seen solutions of people getting accepted with 100*100 size.  How can I make my graph array size less, or perhaps what is the best possible way to accept input in the adjacency list in graph?

P.S.: I tried using vector and map/pairs STL, but since I am not good in STL, I will be more than happy if a non STL solution is presented.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define INF 1e9
int graph[1000][1000], m[1001], n;  //this is the array which I want to decrease
int main(){
    int u, v, flag=0, testCase = 1;
    while(scanf("%d%d", &u, &v), u||v){

        n = 0;
        memset(m, 0, sizeof(m));

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<1000; j++)
            graph[i][j] = INF;

        if(!m[u])
        m[u] = ++n;

        if(!m[v])
        m[v] = ++n;

        graph[m[u]][m[v]] = 1;
        graph[m[u]][m[u]] = 0;
        graph[m[v]][m[v]] = 0;

        while(scanf("%d%d", &u, &v), u||v){
            if(!m[u])
            m[u] = ++n;

            if(!m[v])
            m[v] = ++n;

            graph[m[u]][m[v]] = 1;
            graph[m[u]][m[u]] = 0;
            graph[m[v]][m[v]] = 0;
        }

        for(int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            graph[i][j] = min(graph[i][j], graph[i][k] + graph[k][j]);

        double s = 0.0;

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for(int j=1; j<=n; j++)
        s += graph[i][j];
        //cout<<s<<endl;
        s /= (double)n*(n-1);
        //cout<<s<<endl;
        printf("Case %d: average length between pages = %.3lf clicks\n",testCase++,s);
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Running [here](http://ideone.com/S9nFfT)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem statement [linked above](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=762) says 'Page numbers will always be in the range 1 to 100', I don't understand why you need to keep size = 1000, size = 101 should work just fine. Correct me if I am missing something here.

I modified your code [here](http://ideone.com/QhBkBa)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define INF 1e9
#define MAX_SIZE 100

int graph[MAX_SIZE + 1][MAX_SIZE + 1], n, mapping[MAX_SIZE + 1];
int main() {
    int u, v, flag=0, testCase = 1;
    while(scanf("%d%d", &u, &v), u||v){
        for(int i = 1; i <= MAX_SIZE; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j <= MAX_SIZE; j++) {
                graph[i][j] = INF;
            }
            graph[i][i] = 0;
        }
        int n = 0;
        memset (mapping, 0, sizeof(mapping));
        do {
            if (!mapping[u])
                mapping[u] = ++n;
            if (!mapping[v])
                mapping[v] = ++n;
            graph[mapping[u]][mapping[v]] = 1;
        } while(scanf("%d%d", &u, &v), u||v);

        for(int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
            for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                    graph[i][j] = min(graph[i][j], graph[i][k] + graph[k][j]);

        double s = 0.0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                s += graph[i][j];
        //cout<<s<<endl;
        s /= (double)n*(n-1);
        //cout<<s<<endl;
        printf("Case %d: average length between pages = %.3lf clicks\n",testCase++,s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please list the modifications you did and why you did them? It would help both the asker to know what to change, and the future reviewers to cover points that you didn't cover :)

Comment: @anoop chaurasiya Earlier when I was using size 100*100 I was getting a sum of 198 and number of clicks =0.02 ,so when I changed to 1000*1000 it started working fine!! I thought there was some problem in my implementation,Strangely when I just changed the size to 100 now it's working fine.

Answer (score 6):

## Use the standard library

> I tried using vector and map/pairs STL, but since I am not good in STL, I will be more than happy if a non STL solution is presented.

You should rather ask *for* a detailed standard library based solution ("STL" refers to "standard template library" on which some parts of the standard library are based but which is not the standard library). Honestly, it may take some time in the beginning, but it is totally worth it. Currently, appart from `std::min`, you are not using anything that is C++-specific.

## `using namespace std;` is evil

`using namespace std;` is probably the biggest single mistake that you will see in many tutorials all around the internet. It [is not something you should do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1364752) since it may create name problems and *very* unexpected errors from time to time. Just put `std::` in front of every component you import from the standard library.

## Order your headers

That's not *that* important, but you will probably find it easier to check whether you already included some header if you order them in alphabetical ordering:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
```

## Get rid of dead code

You should try to avoid keeping code that you commented out. You will probably end up deleting it at some point anyway since you won't remember what you wanted to do with it or why it worked/didn't work.

## You don't need to `return 0;` at the end of `main`

When you program reaches the end of the funciton `main`, if it did not find any `return` statement, it will automagically `return 0;`. Note that this is only true for `main`, but in your case, that means that you can get rid of this last line.